# How can i know if it is a random word(or string)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-mining

I want to know which given string is random.

For example, If there was given words (A)"protectsky" and (B)"ptctpkysui", A human would recognize (A) as a meaningful string and (B) as a meaningless string.

In this way, is there any way for the computer to differentiate between any given string in the same way as above?

Machine learning, dictionary matching, entropy calculation, etc.. any method or idea is fine.

It is also okay if the result is a probability value or a specific threshold value.

If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: If you give non English examples you should translate them, otherwise we don't understand. There's no such thing as a "random word". Do you mean a word which doesn't exist in a dictionary, like 'abcdefg'? If so you could use a dictionary of words for this language. Of course it won't contain all the proper names.

Comment: First, I'm just dealing with English case.
So, Is it best way for solve the my problem is dictionanry matching?
I want to know something new ideas. Is there no such thing?

Comment: 'protectsky' is not an English word as far as I know, it wouldn't be in an English dictionary. It looks to me like the problem is not well defined yet, you need to formally decide what is a 'meaningful word' vs 'random word'. If 'meaningful' = in a dictionary, then a dictionary is the logical solution. But if it's something else, please clarify what you mean. For example are you talking about stop words, like determiners and pronouns? Are you talking about complex words that people might not understand? etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from a perfect solution, but it may help you.

You can use the spelling correction suggestions from `hunspell`. If there are no suggestions, it may be "meaningless". If there are suggestions, it is possibly meaningful.  Using your examples:

```
library(hunspell)

TestWords = c("protectsky", "ptctpkysui")
hunspell_suggest(TestWords)

[[1]]
[1] "protect sky"  "protect-sky"  "protectorate"

[[2]]
character(0)
```

You could go a little further, by requiring that the suggestions be not *too* far from the original.

```
library(stringdist)

Possible = unlist(hunspell_suggest("protectsky"))
stringdist(Possible, "protectsky")
[1] 1 1 5
```

Since "protectorate" isn't very close to "protectsky" we would reject it as a possibility. But "protect sky" and "protect-sky"are only at distant of 1, it is likely that they are a "meaningful" version of the test word.